# Open a file with a specific program using cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to open a HTML file using cmd, located in the autostart folder using internet explorer, even tho for example Firefox is selected for standard browser.
I already navigated to the autostart folder.
How can I do that?
Or what is the command for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" file://path_to_file`

Refer to the [command line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/hh826025(v=vs.85)) for IE11 for details of options that you might need

Comment: Thanks, I’ll be testing it when I’m Home!